# C++ Сборка SO library и создание обёртки dll для wine

Tags: c++, dll, wine

У меня есть потребность создать SO библиотеку из исходников C++ и использовать её с обёрткой dll, чтобы работать с ней в Wine.

Изначально я пытался сделать обёртку по инструкции: [https://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib_User's_Guide#Introduction_3](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib_User%27s_Guide#Introduction_3)

А затем, попробовать создать свою SO библиотеку и использовать её в качестве цели.
У меня есть 2 каталога:

1. BuildSO - исходники C++ для компиляции SO библиотеки.
2. BuildDLL - исходники C++ для компиляции DLL обёртки.

Каталог BuildSO:

Файл - linuxfunc.h

```
int MyLinuxFunc(int, int);
```

Файл - linuxfunc.cpp

```
#include "linuxfunc.h"

int main() {
  return 0;
}

int MyLinuxFunc(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Команды компиляции:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -c -o linuxfunc.o linuxfunc.cpp
gcc -shared -o liblinuxfunc.so linuxfunc.o
```

На выходе я получаю SO библиотеку - liblinuxfunc.so

Каталог BuildDLL:

Файл - linuxfunc.h

```
int MyLinuxFunc(int, int);
```

Файл - win.cpp

```
#include  "windef.h"
#include "linuxfunc.h"

int WINAPI MyProxyWinFunc (int a, int b)
{
    return MyLinuxFunc(a,b);
}
```

Файл - win.spec

```
@ stdcall MyWinFunc (long long) MyProxyWinFunc
```

Находясь в каталоге wine-master/win_build/BuildDLL выполняю следующие команды:

1)

```
winemaker . --nosource-fix --dll --single-target win --nomfc -L"/home/ASOFT/i-ershov/wine-master/win_build/BuildSO" -llinuxfunc
```

Ответ:

```
Winemaker 0.8.4
Copyright 2000-2004 François Gouget <fgouget@codeweavers.com> for CodeWeavers
Copyright 2004 Dimitrie O. Paun
Copyright 2009-2012 André Hentschel
Scanning the source directories...
Generating project files...
```

2. 

```
make
```

Ответ:

```
wineg++  -o ..so  win.o    -L/home/ASOFT/i-ershov/wine-master/win_build/BuildSO -llinuxfunc
```

Файл - Makefile

```
### Generated by Winemaker 0.8.4
###
### Invocation command line was
### /usr/bin/winemaker --nosource-fix --dll --single-target win --nomfc -L/home/ASOFT/i-ershov/wine-master/win_build/BuildSO -llinuxfunc


SRCDIR                = .
SUBDIRS               =
DLLS                  = .
LIBS                  =
EXES                  =



### Common settings

CEXTRA                =
CXXEXTRA              =
RCEXTRA               =
DEFINES               =
INCLUDE_PATH          = -I.
DLL_PATH              =
DLL_IMPORTS           =
LIBRARY_PATH          = -L/home/ASOFT/i-ershov/wine-master/win_build/BuildSO
LIBRARIES             = -llinuxfunc


### . sources and settings

__MODULE              = .
__C_SRCS              =
__CXX_SRCS            = win.cpp
__RC_SRCS             =
__LDFLAGS             =
__ARFLAGS             =
__DLL_PATH            =
__DLLS                =
__LIBRARY_PATH        =
__LIBRARIES           =

__OBJS                = $(__C_SRCS:.c=.o) \
            $(__CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o) \
            $(__RC_SRCS:.rc=.res)



### Global source lists

C_SRCS                = $(__C_SRCS)
CXX_SRCS              = $(__CXX_SRCS)
RC_SRCS               = $(__RC_SRCS)


### Tools

CC = winegcc
CXX = wineg++
RC = wrc
AR = ar


### Generic targets

all: $(SUBDIRS) $(DLLS:%=%.so) $(LIBS) $(EXES)

### Build rules

.PHONY: all clean dummy

$(SUBDIRS): dummy
    @cd $@ && $(MAKE)

# Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .cxx .rc .res
DEFINCL = $(INCLUDE_PATH) $(DEFINES) $(OPTIONS)

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CEXTRA) $(DEFINCL) -o $@ $<

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXEXTRA) $(DEFINCL) -o $@ $<

.cxx.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXEXTRA) $(DEFINCL) -o $@ $<

.rc.res:
    $(RC) $(RCFLAGS) $(RCEXTRA) $(DEFINCL) -fo$@ $<

# Rules for cleaning

CLEAN_FILES     = y.tab.c y.tab.h lex.yy.c core *.orig *.rej \
                  \\\#*\\\# *~ *% .\\\#*

clean:: $(SUBDIRS:%=%/__clean__) $(EXTRASUBDIRS:%=%/__clean__)
    $(RM) $(CLEAN_FILES) $(RC_SRCS:.rc=.res) $(C_SRCS:.c=.o) $(CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o)
    $(RM) $(DLLS:%=%.so) $(LIBS) $(EXES) $(EXES:%=%.so)

$(SUBDIRS:%=%/__clean__): dummy
    cd `dirname $@` && $(MAKE) clean

$(EXTRASUBDIRS:%=%/__clean__): dummy
    -cd `dirname $@` && $(RM) $(CLEAN_FILES)

### Target specific build rules
DEFLIB = $(LIBRARY_PATH) $(LIBRARIES) $(DLL_PATH) $(DLL_IMPORTS:%=-l%)

$(__MODULE).so: $(__OBJS) $(__MODULE:.dll=.spec)
    $(CXX) $(__LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(__OBJS) $(__LIBRARY_PATH) $(__DLL_PATH) $(DEFLIB) $(__DLLS:%=-l%) $(__LIBRARIES:%=-l%)
```

После выполнения команды make, а именно:

```
wineg++  -o ..so  win.o    -L/home/ASOFT/i-ershov/wine-master/win_build/BuildSO -llinuxfunc
```

Должна появиться DLL библиотека, или я ошибаюсь?

Я перерыл большое количество интернет-ресурсов, но не смог найти ответ на свой вопрос..

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что у меня не так и как я могу это исправить?

Comment: т.к. ошибки нет, то судя по всему что-то с именем `..so` всё же создаётся (файлы, начинающиеся с точки — скрытые)... поидей `.dll`-библиотеки генерироваться и не должно: в статье по ссылке идёт речь о wine-обёртке, т.е. это `.so`-либа, как те что идут в комплекте с wine'ом в `/usr/lib64/wine*/wine` (YMMV)... поидей можно указать путь к этой библиотеке в `WINEDLLPATH` и wine подцепит её вместо dll'ки с тем же именем...